# Add a UIMenuItem for a specific UITextView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, uimenucontroller, uimenuitem

I have a lot of `UITextView`s in my screen and i want to add a new custom `UIMenuItem` for one of them.

It is possible to add a custom `UIMenuItem` just for a specific `UITextView`?

I use below code but i have my custom button for all `UITextView`s

```
UIMenuItem *menuItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Read" action:@selector(readButtonAction)];
[[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] setMenuItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:menuItem]];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `UIMenuItem`  to be displayed for a specific `UITextView` you can just add  menuItem in `textFieldDidBeginEditing`method and add a specific tag to the `UITextView` so that custom menu item displayed for that only :-

```
-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView

{
  if(textview.tag==999)  //specify for which textveiw you want custom menu 
   {
  [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
   UIMenuItem *menuItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Read" action:@selector(readButtonAction)];
    [[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] setMenuItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:menuItem]];
       }];
     }
 }
```

Comment: Yeah, but @Charles Thierry have right. You need to reset every time when is not my specific UITextView. Just add a else there and setMenuIetems with empty array and will working. Thank your for your answer

Comment: Yes, I thought else part will be handled by you ;)

Answer (score 1):

I did not test it, but you could reset the `menuItems` when one of the `UITextView` become first responder. I'd do that by subclassing `UITextView` and implementing the `becomeFirstResponder`.